# get the last two seconds records of chat using laravel,mysql and angular js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, laravel-5

Hi i am creating a chat box like facebook what i want to do is to get the last two seconds chat messages like we have in the facebook when some fiend on facebook send you a message then if your chat box is open then it appends the message in the end of the box.\

but i am having problem here i am using agularjs and laravel when i send some message and the request runs then it mostly append the messages two times in the chat box.like i say `hello` to other user then it will show two times `hello` their in box
here is my html

```
<ul class="chatbox" ng-repeat="chatData in chatboxData">
    <li>
        <div class="message">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="name"> {{ chatData.sender_fname }} </a>
            <span class="body"> {{ chatData.message }} </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

here is angualr js

```
$scope.showSelecteduserChat = function(chat_id) {
    $http.get(url+'/chatboxChat/'+chat_id).success(function(data){
        $scope.chatboxData = data;
         $interval( function(){ $scope.getlasttwosecMsgs(user_id_chat,chat_id,user); }, 2000);

    });
}
```

and code to get the last two seconds records are

```
$scope.getlasttwosecMsgs = function(chat_id) {
    $http.get(url+'/getlasttwosecMsgs/'+chat_id).success(function(data){
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
          $scope.chatboxData.push(value);
        });
    });
}
```

i am also getting the distinct records from query here is my query

```
$data = DB::table(MESSAGES_TBL)
                ->join(USERS_TBL.' as us', MESSAGES_TBL.'.sender_id', '=', 'us.id')
                ->join(USERS_TBL.' as ur', MESSAGES_TBL.'.receiver_id', '=', 'ur.id')
                ->where(MESSAGES_TBL.'.id_chat_room',$chat_id )
                ->whereRaw("message.date_created > (now() - INTERVAL 2 SECOND)" )
                ->orderBy(MESSAGES_TBL.'.created_at', 'ASC')
                ->select(MESSAGES_TBL.'.id as msg_id',MESSAGES_TBL.'.sen_rec_id',MESSAGES_TBL.'.sender_id',MESSAGES_TBL.'.receiver_id',MESSAGES_TBL.'.created_at',MESSAGES_TBL.'.message',MESSAGES_TBL.'.date_created')
                ->distinct()
                ->get();

            return json_encode($data);
```

here is the image of chat
[image: Chat Box]

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing that logic on server? Why won't you let Angular decide?

Comment: @MinaAbadir i dont have any other logic then this because i am new to angular js i f you have any better logic then please tell me i will implement that

Comment: Why won't you use redis or pusher to send the messages to clients. And on Angular the message is just appended to the chat box.

Comment: Also if you don't want to use sockets, I won't use timing for that. Use a unique id of the last message and get all messages newer than that.

Comment: As i have new to angular js and i did not know about sockets earlier if try to change it now it will take to much time to implement and learn can you please give me an alternate solution for this as i dont have much idea about sockets

Comment: how i can get the last unique id from the chat messages i am using ng-repeat it is generating code for every ul like message like this
<ul class="chats ng-scope" ng-repeat="chatData in chatboxData">
    <li  class="in">
        <div class="message">
            <span class="arrow"> </span>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="name ng-binding"> awais lucky </a>
            <span class="datetime ng-binding"> at  less than a minute ago   </span>
            <span class="body ng-binding"> it is good us </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

Comment: I already provided an alternate one. Use last message unique id and send it to server and get all messages where created_date>last message created date. This will make the api independent of the client interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98973/discussion-between-usama-and-mina-abadir).

Comment: @MinaAbadir i am also facing this problem to i am using timestamp the problem is that mysql timestamp is storing different datetime and php is storing different datetime